# How to draw wave circle shape in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: geometry, shapes, adobe-illustrator

I am new in Illustrator and trying learn how to draw wave shapes (Like image below). I found one interesting image and tried draw it. But I cant. Please help me!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

that would be best done by hand and then traced over with pen tool. Or designed in 3D software and then stylized. those are my solutions.

You can also draw lines and change their thickness using presets in Illustrator.